# React - Cannot load image from a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a list with books in it, and so far everything is working except for the image that I cannot get it to work.
In my list I want to put the image URL, and then I want that image to be shown.

```js
const list = [
   {
      authorName: 'Robin',
      img: 'https://marketplace.canva.com/EADanktU9AE/1/0/251w/canva-green-beach-photo-book-cover-o2wPCwYqW2w.jpg',
      bookName: 'Smart shopping',
      description: 'This is the first book',
      price: '$15'
   },
];

const Main = () => (
   <div className="main-wrapper">
      {list.map(item => (
         <div>
            <h1>{item.authorName}</h1>
            <img src="{item.img}" alt=""/>
            <h2>{item.bookName}</h2>
            <p>{item.description}</p>
            <h3>{item.price}</h3>
         </div>
      ))}
   </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: remove the quotes around the src and you'll be all good: `src={item.img}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the quotes from the image tag. Quotes here takes the value as string, so the src attribute value looks like `src = "{item.img}"` when compiled, Removing the quotes will replace the exact URL.

```
<img src={item.img} alt=""/>
```

Comment: As an aside, it'll be useful to add a `key` prop to the first div inside the mapped list. It could be any of the properties of a list item that is unique, maybe `bookName` for instance.

Comment: Is <div key="bookName"> all I have to do?

Comment: @IbrahimKunushefci, when we are iterating an array, we are supposed to give a `key="some_unique_value"` inorder to maintain uniqueness of the item. Please check the official documentation for more clarity for the use of `key` attribute. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the double quote from src, rather you need to put just curly brackes only.

```js
const list = [
   {
      authorName: 'Robin',
      img: 'https://marketplace.canva.com/EADanktU9AE/1/0/251w/canva-green-beach-photo-book-cover-o2wPCwYqW2w.jpg',
      bookName: 'Smart shopping',
      description: 'This is the first book',
      price: '$15'
   },
];

const Main = () => (
   <div className="main-wrapper">
      {list.map(item => (
         <div>
            <h1>{item.authorName}</h1>
            <img src={item.img} alt=""/>
            <h2>{item.bookName}</h2>
            <p>{item.description}</p>
            <h3>{item.price}</h3>
         </div>
      ))}
   </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<img src="{item.img}" alt=""/>
```

With

```
<img src={item.img} alt=""/>
```